# Does it matter where I place my models on my Resin printer build plate?

Tags: 3d-models, build-plate, hardware

I have a resin 3D printer, so I can print multiple models of a similar size without the overall build time increasing very much. So long as I stay within a set height range.

Presuming that my build plate is level and that my FEP is OK, does it matter where I place the models on my build plate?

For example, should I place the largest items in the center, and smaller ones around the edge, or vice-versa?

Does placing particular models in particular places stress the FEP, induce suction or lead to increased failure risk for other reasons?

For example, is the below terrible placement, or just meh?

[image]

Comment: I don’t own a resin printer, so this is from a layman, but one thing I read is that part orientation is opposite FDM prints, which you want to build flat on the build plate, that resin printers, you want to print tall ways, on edge. The reasoning was that the peeling of each layer off the screen is where failure occurs, and having the smallest cross section peeling at one time was ideal. Also the Z resolution is good, and there are no problems with layer adhesion.

Answer (score 1):

Having only recently begun to print with a resin printer, I've wondered the same. The tension on the FEP is reasonably even across the entire printable surface, and the FEP is slightly larger than the LCD, keeping "edge" prints truly away from the edge.

The deflection of the FEP in the vat may be a millimeter or two greater in the center, but the lift distance is certainly going to be higher than that. My printer's settings is for 8 mm lift between layers, recently changed to 7.5 mm with no complications, other than a warning from Lychee Slicer.

I've found that it's nearly impossible to examine the print for the first few centimeters, so I place the items as close to the front as possible/practical.

This would mean that there's a gradient involved in the deflection of the FEP from the edge to the center, which probably doesn't complicate things and may be a benefit.

Regarding your current layout on the build plate, consider more the removal aspect. The smaller items inside the larger ones are going to be more difficult to remove than the outer smaller items, but not so much more difficult as to complicate matters. The reach of the tool you use to pry under the base would determine how you place the models.

I've added a magnetic removable build plate, but smaller models tend to pop free the supports, making a tool a requirement despite marketing claims. I use the tool size to provide placement reference (close to the front is easy) when building out a plate.